# How to set maximum value of date attribute in Magento?

Tags: attributes, adminhtml, customer, setup-script

I want to set maximum value of "Date of Birth" (dob) attribute of the customer.

I want to set this date only earlier than today (not for future). After change I want to have JS validation on adminhtml backend in customer edit screen.

I want to update this attribute in setup scripts within my module.
How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a new JavaScript validation to the Validation object and tell the "Date of Birth" attribute to use it.

1. **Add a layout update file for the backend area and tell Magento to load a JavaScript file**

   In your `config.xml` add a section like this:

   ```
   <config>
       <!-- ... -->
       <adminhtml>
           <layout>
               <updates>
                   <emzee_dobvalidation>
                       <file>emzee_dobvalidation/emzee_dobvalidation.xml</file>
                   </emzee_dobvalidation>
               </updates> 
           </layout>
       </adminhtml>
   </config>
   ```

   Create the file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/emzee_dobvalidation/emzee_dobvalidation.xml` and add this content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <layout>
       <default>
           <reference name="head">
               <action method="addJs"><script>emzee_dobvalidation/validation.js</script></action>
           </reference>
       </default>
   </layout>
   ```
2. **Add the JavaScript validation to the Validation object**

   Create the file `js/emzee_dobvalidation/emzee_dobvalidation.js` containing this code:

   ```
   Validation.add('validate-customer-dob','Date of birth cannot be in the future!',function(v){
       var test = new Date(v);
       var now = new Date();

       return test.getTime() <= now.getTime();
   });
   ```

   You will not be allowed to set a date in the future.
3. **Reconfigure the "Date of Birth" attribute to use the validation**

   Make sure your extension setup class uses a class inheriting `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`, e.g. `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup`.

   Add this to your `config.xml`:

   ```
   <config>
       <global>
           <resources>
               <emzee_dobvalidation_setup>
                   <setup>
                       <module>Emzee_DobValidation</module>
                       <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                   </setup>
               </emzee_dobvalidation_setup>
           </resources>
       </global>
   </config>
   ```

   Create the setup script updating your attribute (`app/code/community/Emzee/DobValidation/sql/emzee_dobvalidation_setup/install-0.0.1.php`):

   ```
   <?php

   $installer = $this;

   $installer->startSetup();

   $entityTypeId = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
   $installer->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'dob', 'frontend_class', 'validate-customer-dob');

   $installer->endSetup();
   ```
4. **Make sure everything worked**

   If everyting went ok you will get an error when submitting a date in the future:

   [image: No unborn customers anymore!]

Please note that as requested this only is a JavaScript validation. You may want to also check for the correct input on the server side. As this wasn't requested I left it as a home exercise.